# 'Foundational Literature' in Terrestrial Bioacoustics

Tags: literature, graduate-school

I'm an early phd student working with terrestrial bioacoustics. The published literature at the intersection of acoustic ecology, signal processing, statistics and machine learning is moving fast, and accelerating. Please list one or more foundational pieces of literature (peer reviewed articles, books, or reports) you would expect a phd student in bioacoustics to have read under the following topics.

- Acoustic Ecology
- Acoustic Monitoring
- Digital Signal Processing
- Statistics
- Machine Learning

Comment: Welcome @user2596342 your question has received some downvotes likely because it is very broad and open ended. Could you tell us a bit more about what literature you have found already and where specifically you feel you have holes in your knowledge?

Comment: also, a tiny comment: I suggest avoiding the word "seminal", it's a bit off and/or oldfashioned. "foundational" perhaps?

Comment: Hi @user2596342. This link may help with countering the downvotes and rephrasing questions: https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask-beta

Answer (score 7):

I'll list some work here as I think of it. I'll make this an editable "community wiki" answer, and perhaps others can add to it, rather than having everything in separate answers:

### Acoustic Ecology

- [Nature's music: The science of birdsong](https://www.sciencedirect.com/book/9780124730700/natures-music) (Marler and Slabbekoorn, eds, 2004) -- this textbook was a fantastic resource for me when I was getting started in understanding animal sound. It is, of course, only about birdsong.
- Farina & Gage (eds) (2017) ' Ecoacoustics. The ecological role of sounds' Wiley --- Covers a lot of Ecoacoustics ground.

### Acoustic Monitoring

### Digital Signal Processing

- Jerome Sueur (2018) 'Sound Analysis and Synthesis with R' Springer --- It's a practical R guide of course, but lots more besides.
- Steven W Smith, The Scientist and Engineer's Guide to
  Digital Signal Processing, [online book link](http://www.dspguide.com/pdfbook.htm)

### Statistics

### Machine Learning

### Tutorials

### Misc.

Comment: would you mind posting about the community wiki approach over on the meta site?

Comment: @selene I'm not sure what you would like me to post. It's one of the tools that Stack Exchange offers, but I don't have much to say about it!

Answer (score 3):

It's a practical R guide of course, but lots more besides:

- Jerome Sueur (2018) 'Sound Analysis and Synthesis with R' Springer

And covering a lot of Ecoacoustics ground:

- Farina & Gage (eds) (2017) ' Ecoacoustics. The ecological role of sounds' Wiley